# GPIO output is inverted

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi, gpio

im just doing a basic test controlling a LED through the 8080 port everything is working but when  the LED is meant to be off its on and when its meant to be on its off

```html
<body>
        <h1 id="title">Control LED light</h1>

        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 25px;"></p>
        <br>
        <p id="date"><i></i><p>
        <p id="log">ON/OFF</p>
        <p id="log"><input type="checkbox" id="light"></p>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- include socket.io client side script -->
        <script>
                var socket = io(); //load socket.io-client and connect to the host that serves the page
                window.addEventListener("load", function(){ //when page loads
                  var lightbox = document.getElementById("light");
                  lightbox.addEventListener("change", function() { //add event listener for when checkbox changes
                    socket.emit("light", Number(this.checked)); //send button status to server (as 1 or 0)
                  });
                });
                socket.on('light', function (data) { //get button status from client
                  document.getElementById("light").checked = ! data; //change checkbox according to push button on Raspberry Pi
                  socket.emit("light", data); //send push button status to back to server
                });
        </script>

        <div class="footer">
                <a id="back" href="http://jjh22.ddns.net/projects/webled.html"><-BACK-</a>
        </div>
</body>
```

Basicly what can do is invert the look of the checkbox or invert the output of the checkbox.
Any ideas of how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use boolean logic to do it, by doing `Number(!this.checked)`

Comment: im sorry, but can you explain a little further because I've tried that multiple times in many different places of my code wither its what's being sent out or taken in by the .js file.

Comment: sorry I was a little confused this did help tho thank you